# Word for medical treatment gone wrong (not malpractice)

Tags: single-word-requests, medical

I am looking for a word (noun) or expression that describes medical treatment gone wrong, where the treatment was not the correct one, or where something else went wrong, possibly due to unforeseen complications, accidents, inaccurate test results, misdiagnosis, poor medical images, human errors, etc. Errors, *independently* of whether anyone is personally at fault.

I am not looking for the word 'malpractice', which to me indicates negligence, carelessness or incompetence, liable or possibly criminal. 'Wrongful treatment' also does not seem quite right.

An intended usage example is: "We believe this technology will reduce the risk of (medical treatment going wrong)."

Comment: You say that you want a word that means "errors," but why not just use that word? Call them "medical errors."

Comment: I guess that is a possibility. In my native language we have a more official 'technical' term that catches these situations, and is analogous to but broader than 'malpractice'. Directly translated it would be 'error-treatment', without necessarily indicating liability or negligence. I was wondering if there is some precise version of this in English.

Comment: Possibly [iatrogenic](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/iatrogenic) harm?

Comment: Interesting, perhaps. Never heard that one before. Thanks.

Comment: Mistakes? . . . .

Comment: I don't think we have a specific word for it in English.